# How to judge an issue does not contain child issues in PHP API for Redmine?

Tags: php, redmine, children, requirements

Recently, I am working on a project using PHP API for Redmine. Now I need to record whether an issue has any child issues. I have tried to search for related information but failed, so I come here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function to fullfill your requirements, you can have a try.

```
/**
 * @param int $id issueId
 * @return int
 */
public function hasChildIssue($id)
{
    $res = $this->client->api('issue')->show($id, array('include' => 'children'));
    if (!empty($res) && isset($res['issue']['children'])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Reference: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Showing-an-issue